# How to convert matrix in csv to matrix in netlogo

Tags: csv, matrix, netlogo

I have matrix with dimension 10 x 10 in csv file and I want to open it as a matrix too in Netlogo. Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can most easily do this using the csv extension to read in the matrix as a list of lists, and then, if you want to actually create a matrix on which you can do matrix operations, pass the list of lists to the matrix extension.

Say you have a matrix that looks like

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

in a file "mymatrix.csv".  The following code snippit would read the file:

```
let m csv:from-file "mymatrix.csv"
```

That would give you a list of lists with each row being an item in the list:
[[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]]

You could then use the matrix extension to put that into an actual matrix:

```
let mat matrix:from-row-list m
```